# How do I find duplicates between variables?

Tags: r, duplicates, spss

I have a `.csv` file that contains ten columns of data. Each column will have duplicates *within* them but there should **not** be an duplicates *between* columns. How do I verify this?

I hope to perform this function in either SPSS or R.

Comment: Could you try adding an example snippet of your data with some fictional values? I'm not sure I understand what you mean by duplicates within columns and between columns.

Answer (score 0):

We check if there are duplicates of the dputs of these columns:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:3,b=4:6,c=1:3)
df
#   a b c
# 1 1 4 1
# 2 2 5 2
# 3 3 6 3

col_dputs <- sapply(df,function(x) capture.output(dput(x)))

# only redundant columns
names(df)[duplicated(col_dputs)]
#[1] "c"

# all duplicated columns
names(df)[duplicated(col_dputs) | duplicated(col_dputs,fromLast = TRUE)]
# [1] "a" "c"
```